# Exakte Verwendung des Apostrophes

Tags: apostrophe

Da man ein Apostroph im Deutschen ja nur verwendet, wenn man entweder Wortteile weglässt oder nur bei einer possessiven Bestimmung, wenn dabei eine Marke bzw. ein Eigenname entsteht, frage ich mich, ab wann ein Name als Eigenname bzw. Marke gilt.

Die Phrase `Pauls Hund` ist richtig, wenn Paul aber einen Laden o. Ä. gründet, würde es `Paul's Laden` heißen, da dort eine Marke etabliert wird. Ich frage mich, wo die Grenze ist; wo man ein Apostroph verwendet und wo nicht.

Comment: Das ist nicht das Etablieren einer Marke, sondern ein Konstrukt, das  *Deppenapostroph* genannt wird. Zwischen einen Namen und ein Genitiv-s gehört im Deutschen einfach kein Apostroph hin. Nur *Thomas' Laden* wäre in Ordnung, weil da das Genitiv-s wegfällt.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph

Comment: Der Apostroph wird gelegentlich zur Verdeutlichung der Grundform eines Personennamens gebraucht:

    vor dem Genitiv-s;
    Zum Beispiel
        Andrea’s Blumenecke (zur Unterscheidung vom männlichen Vornamen Andreas)
        Willi’s Würstchenbude

Comment: @choXer: Weil man glaubt, Blumenecke sei Andreas Nachname und es sei vielleicht eine Bäckerei? Wie erklärt sich dann Kaiser's Supermarkt u. dgl.?

Comment: @userunknown Nee, damit es nicht Andreas seine ist ;-) Willi und Kaiser wollen halt zeigen, dass der Laden nach ihnen benannt wurde und nicht nach Herrn Willis und Frau Kaisers...

Comment: Marketingleute leben in einem Paralleluniversum, in dem das richtig ist. Man schreibt da auch "Schwarze Johannisbeere Joghurt" und "Kartoffel Püree".

Comment: @userunknown immerhin haben sie's in die Rechtschreibregeln und den Duden geschafft..

Comment: @choXer: Beeindruckt mich wenig. Der Duden ist ein Verlagsprodukt einer GmbH ohne höhere Weihen.

Comment: @userunknown falls du dich auf die alten Kaiser's Supermärkte beziehst ... das Unternehmen wurde im 19. Jhd gegründet. Da war es noch "erlaubt" den Apostroph so zu setzen. Der Rest ist Geschichte. Ähnliches sieht man heute noch bei Beck's.

Comment: @mtwde: Die Rechtschreibung kennt aber kein "Wer zuerst kommt, mahlt zuerst" - man darf sich auch an Regeln halten, die erst nach aufgestellt wurden, nachdem man eine Schreibweise benutzt hat, die den neuen Regeln nach, falsch ist. Zweitens kann man sich die Gründe zu Gemüte führen, die zu einem Regelwerk geführt haben und dann aus Einsicht in deren Sinn diese beachten. Das setzt jedoch Hirn und Ethos voraus - beides ist selten vorhanden, in Kombination besonders. Feiste Ignoranz ist billiger.

Comment: Siehe auch http://deppenapostroph.de/

Comment: @userunknown Das sollten wir dann auch all den Leuten sagen, die Mueller oder Schroeder heißen. Und auch all denen, die Voß oder Nußbaum heißen. Und was ist mit den ganzen Wolffs? Sind ja alles offensichtliche Schreibfehler. Aber man könnte auch einsehen, dass Namen sich der Rechtschreibung entziehen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Verwendung des Apostrophs regeln §§ 62, 96 und 97 des [amtlichen Regelwerks](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf), die du in deiner Frage bereits mehr oder weniger zusammengefasst hast.

Hier kommen ins Spiel

> (§ 96.1) Eigennamen,  deren  Grundform auf  einen  s-Laut endet. Sie bekommen im Genitiv den  Apostroph,  wenn  sie  nicht  einen  Artikel,  ein  Possessivpronomen oder dergleichen bei sich haben.

Also zum Beispiel: Andreas' Würstchenbude, was die Würstchenbude eines Andreas wäre.

> (§97) Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.

Also zum Beispiel: Andrea's Würstchenbuden, was die Würstchenbude einer Andrea wäre.

So viel zur offziellen geschriebenen Sprache. Nun kommen wir zur Marke

> Die Phrase Pauls Hund ist richtig, wenn Paul aber einen Laden o. Ä. gründet, würde es Paul's Laden heißen, da dort eine Marke etabliert wird

Dieser Satz ist nicht richtig. Es *muss* nicht Paul's Laden heißen, aber (und nun wird es interessant) Paul kann seinen Laden nennen wie er will.

> Pauls Laden
>
> Paul's Laden
>
> pauls laden
>
> pAuL's LaDeN

Das wären alle erlaubte "Marken"-Namen, die er auf sein Schild schreiben könnte. Es ist ihm nicht verboten. Dazu muss er auch nichts beim DPMA anmelden. Er müsste sich zwar vielleicht immer wieder anhören, dass da ein Schreibfehler auf dem Schild steht, aber er weiß es besser, denn vielleicht ist es ja ein Ableger der berühmten "Paul's"-Kette aus Amerika und aus diesem Land kennen wir auch bereits "McDonald’s".

Also, würde der Laden "Wunderland" heißen wäre es Pauls Laden. Würde er ihn "Paul's Laden" nennen, hieße Pauls Laden Paul's Laden.

Comment: "Andrea's Würstchenbude" was wird denn hier ausgelassen?

Comment: @infinitezero "E: Von dem Apostroph als Auslassungszeichen zu unterscheiden ist der gele-gentliche Gebrauch dieses Zeichens zur Verdeutlichung der Grundform eines Personennamens vor der Genitivendung -s oder vor dem Adjektivsuffix -sch:Carlo’s Taverne, Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie" würde dir da Recht geben...